Why do English and German have relatively large vowel inventories?
Why do English and German have relatively large vowel inventories?



are you interested in the historical developments that led to this (which we certainly can answer), or are you asking about the reason that those particular developments happened (which cannot be answered)

@Tristan The historical developments then
